# SCDF dataflow server 2.4.2 composed task

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I use SCDF with skipper server 2.3.2 and dataflow server 2.4.2. deployed with Docker-compose
I build a task with composed-task-runner 2.1.3 release
I try with my task but even with samples, composed-task-runner doesn't launch tasks

Example :

```
composed-task-runner && mytask && myTask

2020-04-14 14:40:41.633  INFO 231 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskExecutor'
2020-04-14 14:40:41.752  INFO 231 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: POSTGRES
2020-04-14 14:40:41.885  INFO 231 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2020-04-14 14:40:42.083 DEBUG 231 --- [           main] o.s.c.t.a.c.DataFlowConfiguration        : Not configuring basic security for accessing the Data Flow Server
2020-04-14 14:40:46.922 DEBUG 231 --- [           main] o.s.c.t.r.s.TaskRepositoryInitializer    : Initializing task schema for postgresql database
2020-04-14 14:40:47.461 DEBUG 231 --- [           main] BatchConfiguration$ReferenceTargetSource : Initializing lazy target object
2020-04-14 14:40:47.552 DEBUG 231 --- [           main] o.s.c.t.r.support.SimpleTaskRepository   : Starting: TaskExecution{executionId=102, parentExecutionId=null, exitCode=null, taskName='testComposedTask2', startTime=Tue Apr 14 14:40:47 GMT 2020, endTime=null, exitMessage='null', externalExecutionId='null', errorMessage='null', arguments=[xx=7777, --spring.cloud.data.flow.platformname=default, --spring.cloud.task.executionid=102, --spring.cloud.data.flow.taskappname=composed-task-runner]}
2020-04-14 14:40:47.675  INFO 231 --- [           main] .t.a.c.ComposedtaskrunnerTaskApplication : Started ComposedtaskrunnerTaskApplication in 33.768 seconds (JVM running for 38.059)
2020-04-14 14:40:47.743 DEBUG 231 --- [           main] o.s.c.t.r.support.SimpleTaskRepository   : Updating: TaskExecution with executionId=102 with the following {exitCode=0, endTime=Tue Apr 14 14:40:47 GMT 2020, exitMessage='null', errorMessage='null'}
2020-04-14 14:40:47.831  INFO 231 --- [       Thread-7] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskExecutor'
2020-04-14 14:40:47.836  INFO 231 --- [       Thread-7] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-04-14 14:40:47.852  INFO 231 --- [       Thread-7] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-04-14 14:40:47.909  INFO 231 --- [       Thread-7] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Could you help me? I am with a Postgres DB

New remark :

I build a new composed task as said in the documentation :

testComposedTaskA with definition myTask && timestamp

dataflow:>task list

```
╔═══════════════════════════╤═══════════════════╤═══════════╤═══════════╗
║         Task Name         │  Task Definition  │description│Task Status║
╠═══════════════════════════╪═══════════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╣
║testComposedTaskA-myTask   │myTask             │           │UNKNOWN    ║
║testComposedTaskA-timestamp│timestamp          │           │UNKNOWN    ║
║testComposedTaskA          │myTask && timestamp│           │UNKNOWN    ║
╚═══════════════════════════╧═══════════════════╧═══════════╧═══════════╝
```

dataflow:>task launch testComposedTaskA
Launched task 'testComposedTaskA' with execution id 135

dataflow:>task execution list

```
╔═════════════════╤═══╤════════════════════════════╤════════════════════════════╤═════════╗
║    Task Name    │ID │         Start Time         │          End Time          │Exit Code║
╠═════════════════╪═══╪════════════════════════════╪════════════════════════════╪═════════╣
║testComposedTaskA│135│Fri Apr 17 15:04:42 GMT 2020│Fri Apr 17 15:04:42 GMT 2020│0        ║
╚═════════════════╧═══╧════════════════════════════╧════════════════════════════╧═════════╝
```

Sub-tasks are never executed . In the samples, we can see the sub task as executed
What is wrong?

As request, the dataflow server start log 
Hi the dataflow server start log :

```
dataflow-server             | 2020-04-20 07:43:24.047  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
dataflow-server             | 2020-04-20 07:43:24.061  INFO 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
dataflow-server             | 2020-04-20 07:43:27.735 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.t.c.SimpleTaskAutoConfiguration    : Using org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.DefaultTaskConfigurer TaskConfigurer
dataflow-server             | 2020-04-20 07:43:27.745 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.t.c.DefaultTaskConfigurer          : EntityManager was found, using JpaTransactionManager
dataflow-server             | 2020-04-20 07:43:28.282  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: POSTGRES
skipper                     | 2020-04-20 07:43:28.294  INFO 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
dataflow-server             | 2020-04-20 07:43:28.505  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.d.s.b.SimpleJobServiceFactoryBean  : No database type set, using meta data indicating: POSTGRES
dataflow-server             | 2020-04-20 07:43:28.975  WARN 1 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
dataflow-server             | 2020-04-20 07:43:29.392  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
dataflow-server             | 2020-04-20 07:43:32.150  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.c.DataFlowControllerAutoConfiguration : Skipper URI [http://skipper-server:7577/api]
dataflow-server             | 2020-04-20 07:43:32.614  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9393"]
dataflow-server             | 2020-04-20 07:43:32.764  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 9393 (http) with context path ''
dataflow-server             | 2020-04-20 07:43:32.780  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.d.s.s.DataFlowServerApplication    : Started DataFlowServerApplication in 68.947 seconds (JVM running for 78.165)
dataflow-server             | 2020-04-20 07:43:33.396  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.c.d.s.s.LauncherInitializationService : Added 'Local' platform account 'default' into Task Launcher repository.
```

The log at the start of the task :

```
2020-04-20 08:01:58.886  INFO 115 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-04-20 08:01:59.008  INFO 115 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 68ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
2020-04-20 08:02:00.545  INFO 115 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=56219e3d-5a2d-3fb3-8901-c3dad5be90af
2020-04-20 08:02:00.943  INFO 115 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cd22d842] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-04-20 08:02:01.049  INFO 115 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e93cdb3f] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-04-20 08:02:01.062  INFO 115 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.configuration.TaskBatchAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.configuration.TaskBatchAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$529283ce] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-04-20 08:02:01.094  INFO 115 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.listener.BatchEventAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.listener.BatchEventAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9ae88dd1] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-04-20 08:02:02.529  INFO 115 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-04-20 08:02:03.239  INFO 115 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-04-20 08:02:04.489  INFO 115 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2020-04-20 08:02:07.075  INFO 115 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.13.Final}
2020-04-20 08:02:07.111  INFO 115 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2020-04-20 08:02:08.896  INFO 115 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2020-04-20 08:02:10.736  INFO 115 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
2020-04-20 08:02:10.825  INFO 115 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
2020-04-20 08:02:10.843  INFO 115 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@3eb91815
2020-04-20 08:02:11.457  INFO 115 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-04-20 08:02:11.675 DEBUG 115 --- [           main] o.s.c.t.c.SimpleTaskAutoConfiguration    : Using org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.DefaultTaskConfigurer TaskConfigurer
2020-04-20 08:02:11.679 DEBUG 115 --- [           main] o.s.c.t.c.DefaultTaskConfigurer          : EntityManager was found, using JpaTransactionManager
2020-04-20 08:02:11.902  INFO 115 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskExecutor'
2020-04-20 08:02:12.005  INFO 115 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: POSTGRES
2020-04-20 08:02:12.107  INFO 115 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2020-04-20 08:02:12.203 DEBUG 115 --- [           main] o.s.c.t.a.c.DataFlowConfiguration        : Not configuring basic security for accessing the Data Flow Server
2020-04-20 08:02:15.942 DEBUG 115 --- [           main] o.s.c.t.r.s.TaskRepositoryInitializer    : Initializing task schema for postgresql database
2020-04-20 08:02:16.551 DEBUG 115 --- [           main] BatchConfiguration$ReferenceTargetSource : Initializing lazy target object
2020-04-20 08:02:16.617 DEBUG 115 --- [           main] o.s.c.t.r.support.SimpleTaskRepository   : Starting: TaskExecution{executionId=136, parentExecutionId=null, exitCode=null, taskName='testComposedTaskA', startTime=Mon Apr 20 08:02:16 GMT 2020, endTime=null, exitMessage='null', externalExecutionId='null', errorMessage='null', arguments=[--spring.cloud.data.flow.platformname=default, --spring.cloud.task.executionid=136, --spring.cloud.data.flow.taskappname=composed-task-runner]}
2020-04-20 08:02:16.686  INFO 115 --- [           main] .t.a.c.ComposedtaskrunnerTaskApplication : Started ComposedtaskrunnerTaskApplication in 31.176 seconds (JVM running for 34.541)
2020-04-20 08:02:16.717 DEBUG 115 --- [           main] o.s.c.t.r.support.SimpleTaskRepository   : Updating: TaskExecution with executionId=136 with the following {exitCode=0, endTime=Mon Apr 20 08:02:16 GMT 2020, exitMessage='null', errorMessage='null'}
2020-04-20 08:02:16.778  INFO 115 --- [       Thread-7] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskExecutor'
2020-04-20 08:02:16.784  INFO 115 --- [       Thread-7] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-04-20 08:02:16.803  INFO 115 --- [       Thread-7] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-04-20 08:02:16.854  INFO 115 --- [       Thread-7] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

the docker compose used :

```
  dataflow-server:
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/dataflow
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=rootpw
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME=org.postgresql.Driver
      - spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
      - spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect

    entrypoint: "./wait-for-it.sh -t 240 postgres:5432 -- java -jar /maven/spring-cloud-dataflow-server.jar"

  skipper-server:
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/dataflow
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=rootpw
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME=org.postgresql.Driver
    entrypoint: "./wait-for-it.sh -t 240 postgres:5432 -- java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /spring-cloud-skipper-server.jar"
```

I hope, it will be an help.

Regards

Frederic

Answer (score 0):

From the log: `composed-task-runner && mytask && myTask`, the syntax for creating the Composed Task definition looks incorrect.

The app name `composed-task-runner` should not be part of the task DSL.

You can check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-composed-tasks) for the detailed documentation on how to create and manage composed tasks.

Comment: Hi, I add a new remark in my post with a sample and my sub task aren't executed.

Comment: Hi, Could you post the log from SCDF when the composed task application started? That will give us some idea of what's going on here. I suspect you might have not configured your database for the SCDF correctly. Are you sure the SCDF is also configured to use the correct Postgres DB configuration?

Comment: Hi, I add the log at the dataflow server start and the log at the launch of the composed task. I hope it can be an help. . For me SCDF is well configured to use Postgres, 
 Regards